# Help getting dashboard snapshots to chatter and groups

Tags: dashboard, chatter-feed-tracking, snapshot

I'm having issues getting the menu to pop up on dashboard images that allows me to post them to chatter.

As you can see in the screenshots below, I've enabled feed tracking on reports and I've Enabled Dashboard Component Snapshots. Based on what I've read, at this point, I should see the menu popup when I hover over a dashboard graph, but I don't. [Dashboard Component Snapshots Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txyHE.png)[image: Feed Tracking Enabled]

Please let me know what exactly I seem to be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Dashboards that you need to enable feed tracking for, not Reports. Here's the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_post_to_dashboard_feed.htm) for posting dashboard snapshots.

Comment: Gosh. I knew it had to be something simple that I was missing. Thanks @alouie